# Samsung Galaxy Exhibit - Email Photo Problem

Tags: email, photos

I have a Samsung Galaxy Exhibit. When my husband sends me photos in email I can see the small preview picture but when I click on it it reverts to an older picture that he sent me. I think I accidentally locked it to that older picture. How do I unlock it? I can see others pictures with no problem. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the original Samsung application is not good enough and has some bugs.

So you can use apps from your mail service like Gmail and Yahoo applications or use applications which support multiple email services like Aqua Mail.

Comment: You could provide links to the apps you mention to make your answer more useful.